# how to create cnn without flatten layer. I dont want fully connected convolution neural network

Tags: deep-learning

I have a predictive analysis problem. I have to do a simple classification as we do in machine learning. I want my code without flattening the layer. After removing the flattening layer with Keras I am getting an error as mentioning below.

```
ValueError: Error when checking target: expected dense_8 to have 3 dimensions, but got array with shape (76322, 1)
```

What should I do for solving this error?

```
from keras.layers.convolutional import Conv2D, MaxPooling2D
x_train = x_train.reshape(x_train.shape[0], x_train.shape[1], 1)
#y_train = y_train.reshape(y_train.shape[0], y_train.shape[1], 1)
seed(2017)
conv = Sequential()
conv.add(Conv1D(20, 4, input_shape =x_train.shape[1:3] , activation('relu'))
conv.add(MaxPooling1D(1))
#conv.add(Dropout(0.1))
#conv.add(Flatten())

conv.add(Dense(1, activation = 'sigmoid'))
sgd = Adam(lr = 0.001, beta_1=0.9,beta_2=0.7, decay = 0)
conv.compile(loss = 'binary_crossentropy', optimizer = sgd, metrics = ['accuracy'])
conv.fit(x_train, y_train, batch_size = 200, epochs = 100, verbose = 1)
```

Comment: This is probably because of the shape of your `y_train`. Please specify the shapes of your `x_train` and `y_train`

Comment: The Flatten() layer actually transforms its inputs to a 2 dimen array. Since, you are not using it, the last Dense layer is expecting a 3 dimen output. The input of the last Dense layer is also a 3 dimen array.

Comment: x_train.shape=(76322, 446, 1) and y_train.shape=(76322,) @A

Comment: Why don't you put the proper code here? The error mentions `dense_8`, I do not see that many layers in the code you posted here.